# How should I include Package References in a VSIX project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

My solution creates a Visual Studio Package from multiple projects, using multiple NuGet packages.

All of the Nuget packages are specified in the project files using PackageReference (rather than the older packages.config file). I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I have had a problem, that the DLLs referenced by NuGet Packages are not included in the VSIX installation.

There is a solution to this problem, described in [this article by Daniel Cazzulino](http://www.cazzulino.com/include-dlls-in-vsix.html), by adding the following code to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GetVsixSourceItemsDependsOn>$(GetVsixSourceItemsDependsOn);IncludeNuGetResolvedAssets</GetVsixSourceItemsDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="IncludeNuGetResolvedAssets" DependsOnTargets="ResolveNuGetPackageAssets">
  <ItemGroup>
    <VSIXCopyLocalReferenceSourceItem Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"  /> 
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This does work, but it blows up the size of the installation from about 20MB to about 40MB.

The installation now includes a lot of PDB files, which I don't really need.

More significantly, it brings in about 46MB of Visual Studio DLLs which are not necessary, because they are part of Visual Studio.

Is there a better way to ensure that the referenced NuGet packages are included in the VSIX, without inflating the installation with these other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple script like this:

```
<Target Name="IncludeNuGetPackageReferences" AfterTargets="GetVsixSourceItems">
  <ItemGroup>
    <VSIXSourceItem Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' == 'Newtonsoft.Json'" />
    <VSIXSourceItem Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' == 'xxx'" />
 ... </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You can specify what assemblies should be included into `.vsix` . And it won't copy the `unnecessary VS assemblies` after tests in my machine. Hint from [smourier](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5899#issuecomment-358975346), thanks to him.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I haven't had time to try it yet, but I will do very soon. If it works I will certainly mark it as the answer.

Comment: Where does this go? In the csproj? (are you missing the closing </ItemGroup>

Comment: Yes, you can add the script in csproj, within the project node. Just update the end tag of itemgroup, thanks for the reminder.